# Change select value through ID

Tags: javascript

I need to change select option through ID or title (for now through value) on link click.

For example : If i click on **120*100 cm** link, the option with this ID should be selected.

Hope it's clear.

**Link example :**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="group_1.value='90*300 cm'">90*300 cm</a>
```

**Select list :**

```
<select onchange="design.ajax.getPrice()" name="group[1]" id="group_1">
   <option value="33" selected="selected" title="90*300 cm" id="90*300 cm">90*300 cm</option>
   <option value="77" title="120*100 cm" id="120*100 cm">120*100 cm</option>
   <option value="78" title="120*150 cm" id="120*150 cm">120*150 cm</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `120*100 cm` => `onclick="group_1.value='77'"`

Comment: Already done. Now im using `group_1.value` but it's not working because the option value is another number that i can't get it.

Comment: @dsfq. I can't get the the option value. I need another way to change the option through ID because there are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the element via document.getElementById("idofSelect") and then just change it's value to what you want.

note that this method will work with the VALUE of the option, not the text inside it.

like so:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('group_1').value='90*300 cm'">90*300 cm</a>
```

It is better practice to separate the behaviour on click from the html so you could bind the event in a similar way through javascript.

EDIT: Missread the question, as the answer above says, you can get the element and set attribute selected to true.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('90*300').selected=true">90*300 cm</a>
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you ! Just one last thing... I need to put the links in select menu. `onclick="document.getElementById('90*300').selected=true"` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this by id, set the option's selected attribute instead of the select value

```html
<select  name="group[1]" id="group_1">
   <option value="33" selected="selected" title="90*300 cm" id="90*300 cm">90*300 cm</option>
   <option value="77" title="120*100 cm" id="120*100 cm">120*100 cm</option>
   <option value="78" title="120*150 cm" id="120*150 cm">120*150 cm</option>
</select>

<a href="javascript:;" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('90*300 cm').selected=true;">90*300 cm</a>
```

Remark: You should think about getting rid of special chars like * and space in the id.

Comment: Same answer above. Thanks. Special chars like * and space in the id could cause a problem ?

Comment: In [html5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) spaces are not allowed in ids, other html specs are even more restrictive.To avoid problems/confusion when applying css or javascript selectors I recommend avoiding the use of ["*", ".", ",", ":", "[", "]", "+", "~"] unless you really have no other choice, although they are allowed by spec.

Comment: Ok noted. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea how to put the links in select menu ? `onclick="document.getElementById('90*300').selected=true"` doesn't work.